# How to setup HSQLDB for Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, xampp, hsqldb

I want to use hibernate in combination with hsqldb.
I used hibernate before with xampp/mysql... but now I have no idea how to set up the HSQLDB manager to use it with hibernate...

I wrote in my config file this for mysql:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oadturk

but now I have no idea how to access HSQLDB

thanks!

Comment: Firstly, your question lacks enough information to diagnose the problem. Secondly, you don't need to access HSQLDB. Hibernate keeps them transparent. Just config Hibernate to use HSQL rather than MySQL and that's it. The connection string (which you've shown above) is one of the things that should change along with a couple of other configs.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use HSQLDB as a server, similar to MySQL, so you can connect to it with the DatabaseManager as well as your Hibernate app.

See the Guide on how to run the server. You can then use a URL such as this to connect to the database.

```
   jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/oadturk
```

The Guide chapter is here:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html